# Swiping up and pulling down quickly causing a big blank space in the feed

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I was scrolling down (swiping up) and then I pulled down. Hard.

> [image]

Comment: you broke it!!!

Comment: Just hold it upside down and tap lightly

Comment: Take a Motrin and schedule a follow up for next week.

Comment: I'd like to nominate this question for "Titles that you'd think were from Araqde"

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi umm... actually not really Arqade, you don't want to know the search results of "pulled too far". :D

Comment: I like it when programs break as if physically damaged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.0.20 this is fixed since we moved onto a new pull to refresh library.